# How can I modify the $PATH used by my vagrant provisioning script?

Tags: linux, centos, vagrant, path

I have a shell script in /etc/profile.d that adds some directories to my $PATH, but vagrant doesn't see when running a privileged provisioning script.  This uses sudo and sudo does not see this modified $PATH.

Is there a way to get vagrant to see this path?

EDIT: Added some clarifying words.  I'm just looking for how to modify the $PATH in a privileged provisioning script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/profile` (and `/etc/profile.d`) are sourced only when you establish an interactive session. Vagrant's SSH connection is non-interactive and these files are not used.

You need to put your `PATH` in a file that gets sourced on non-interactive login. If you use bash, then in `/etc/.bash.bashrc` or `.bashrc` for `vagrant` user.

Comment: Provisioning scripts are run as sudo, though, so they won't get that PATH variable either.

Comment: By default, provisioning scripts are run via "sudo".  Putting a modification in ~/.bash_profile for vagrant user will not effect the PATH used within the provisioning script.

Comment: My vagrant provisioning script runs a command called "r10k" which calls another command called "puppet".  r10k assumes that puppet is in my path.  It isn't.  Therefore I'm trying to get it in there!

Comment: I updated the answer I the meantime, for non-interactive bash `/etc/.bash.bashrc` is sourced.